# Character encoding in python to replace 'u2019' with '

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, character-encoding, lxml

I have tried numerous ways to encode this to the end result `"BACK RUSHIN'"` with the most important character being the right apostrophe `'`.

I would like a way of getting to this end result using some of the built in functions Python has where there is no discrimination between a normal string and a unicode string.

This was the code I was using to retrieve the string: `str(unicode(etree.tostring(root.xpath('path')[0],method='text', encoding='utf-8'),errors='ignore')).strip()`

With the result being: `'BACK RUSHIN'` the thing being the apostrophe `'` is missing.

Another way was: `root.xpath('path/text()')`

And that result was: `u'BACK RUSHIN\u2019'` in python.

Lastly if I try: `u'BACK RUSHIN\u2019'.encode('ascii', 'replace')`

The result is: `'BACK RUSHIN?'`

Please no replace functions, I would like to make use of pythons codec libraries.
Also no printing the string because it is being held in a variable.

Thanks

Comment: So you want to read `’` (RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK) from the XML, but translate it to `'` (APOSTROPHE) ?

Comment: This is not a codec problem. As Rob implies, those are two entirely distinct characters. Turning one into the other is a matter of replacement, not encoding. The (misleadingly named) `unidecode` module is no more than a set of replacements from non-ASCII characters to sort-of-similar-looking ASCII ones, for desperate situations when you have to interface with systems that can't do Unicode. Otherwise it's usually a bad idea to mangle strings this way.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
>>> import unidecode
>>> unidecode.unidecode(u'BACK RUSHIN\u2019')
"BACK RUSHIN'"
```

[unidecode](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode)

Comment: might be worth mentioning that you have to install `unidecode`.